# How to send a CSV file record by record to an Azure Event hub using Python as a real time data stream

Tags: python-3.x, azure, csv, azure-eventhub

I have tried sending messages to event hub using sample code provided on Microsoft Documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send). Can I use same code to Send CSV file records to event hub

Comment: Regarding record by record, do you mean send each message in each cell in .csv file?

Comment: No Ivan. Record by record means sending whole record or group of record in one go

Comment: Then what's your problem? you don't know how to fetch the record from .csv? If you can fetch the record from .csv file, you can use send method to send it. Or something else?

Comment: Or do you mean that send batch of eventData? if that's the case, please refer to the updated section the post below.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: yes Ivan, I have created JSON object for every record and sent it as a JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 0904:** If you mean to send batch of EventData, please follow the code below:

```
ADDRESS = "amqps://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/xxx"

# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "xxx"

#this generator method is just an example, please implement your own logic in the data_generator
def data_generator():
    for i in range(5):
        yield b"hello world!!! hhhhhhhhheee"


if not ADDRESS:
    raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

# Create Event Hubs client
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
client.run()  

#send the batch of eventData
data = EventData(batch=data_generator())
sender.send(data)
```

---

If you mean send each message in each cell in .csv file, `you can write your own logic to fetch each message in .csv file`(please try to google for that implementation), then use `for` loop to send them to event hub.

Just a few changes in the code in the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#send-events):

```
logger = logging.getLogger("azure")

ADDRESS = "amqps://xx.servicebus.windows.net/xxx"

# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "xxxx"

if not ADDRESS:
    raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

# Create Event Hubs client
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)

#if you ommit the parameter partition="0", the events will be distributed to all available partitions via round-robin
sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
client.run()  

#you should write your own logic to fetch each message in .csv file
#you then can use for loop to send each message in .csv like below, the following is just an test example
for i in range(10):
    print("Sending message: {}".format(i))
    sender.send(EventData("this is msg: "+str(i)))
```